# What Star Wars fan video has two Jedi fighting in a forest with a Celtic soundtrack?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

I remember a few years ago I stumbled upon a Star Wars fan video that was brilliant. It was an encounter in a forest on a lost planet between a dark and a light Jedi, and their fight to death, with a lovely Celtic soundtrack. The actors and producers were of Asian descent.

I'd love a reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Art of the Saber*, available [here](http://download.theforce.net/theater/fxprojects/artofthesaber/artofthesaber.mov) for download.  The Breton-Celtic music is *Gortoz a ran* ['I'm waiting'], from [Denez Prigent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denez_Prigent).

> A light saber fight sequence with the flavor of a Hong Kong martial arts action movie. This short is set in a dense forest, where a young man, willing to leave his loved ones behind to help fight in the Revolution, clashes with an enemy in a battle where only one will remain standing. Music by Denez Prigent and a monologue extracted from an authentic Civil War love letter written in 1861, help to set the tone for this movie.